# Get duration video MX Player Android in Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi, video, firemonkey

I can not understand how to get a full-time video. There api https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api there is a description

> duration Added in 1.7.23 Type: int Value: Duration of last played
>   video in milliseconds. This extra will not exist if playback is
>   completed.

I try to get as

```
procedure VideoDuration;
  begin
    Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.mxtech.intent.result.VIEW'));
    iDuration := -1;
    Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('duration'), iDuration);
    Label2.Text := IntToStr(iDuration);
   end;
```

Does not work, I need help!!!

Comment: I don't understand your question and can't work out what "doesn't work" means. Please be specific.

Comment: I do not know how to get Duration. The above code does not allow to get it done

Comment: Why did you call putExtra rather than getExtra?

Comment: Because I do not have knowledge. Give the right example please.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it you are calling the wrong function. You should use `putExtra` to change state. That's not what you want to do. You want to read the state and so should call `getIntExtra`.

```
var
  Duration: Integer;
....
Duration := Intent.getIntExtra(StringToJString('duration'), -1);
```

Comment: Okay. I'll try and write

Comment: As a result, see -2                                      Label2.Text := IntToStr(Intent.getIntExtra(StringToJString('duration'), -2));

Comment: That means that there is no integer extra with that name

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to get the value in the wrong point in time? I tried to obtain data on the timer 7 seconds after launch video. But while my program is unloaded from memory ...